# jquery ajax returns 401 even after logging in

Tags: java, ajax, jax-rs, session-variables

I have a jax-rs application in which I have this resource:

```
@Path("login")
public class Login {
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @POST
    public Response login(@FormParam("username") String username,
                          @FormParam("password") String password){
        if(isAuthenticated(username,password)) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username",username);
            return Response.ok().build();
        }
        return Response.status(401).build();
    }
    private static boolean isAuthenticated(String userName, String password) {
        // code that checks user credentials
    }
}
```

And I also have this filter applied on all urls:

```
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (servletResponse instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
            if(!request.getRequestURI().contains("login")){
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                if(session.getAttribute("username")==null){
                    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
                    response.setStatus(401);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Now I have this filter applied to allow cross-origin requests:

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(servletResponse instanceof HttpServletResponse){
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

I have verified that the filter works by inspecting response headers in browser when requesting many urls.

using Postman I verified that login works and I can access any resource after login.

But using cross-domain ajax I make a post request using this code:

```
 $.post("http://example.com/login",{
     username: "ahmad",
     password: "ahmad"
 })
```

and then I'm doing another ajax to a resource like this:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "http://example.com/task",
            xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
            }
 }).then((data) => {
                   // do something with data
 })
```

The second request returns 401 unauthorized even though I did login and I'm not seeing any `no Access-Control-Allow-Origin ...` message in console, just 401 unauthorized.

Now I inspected `session.getAttribute("username")` in `AuthFilter` in second request and it returns null as if the session is invalidated but it's not.

So what's going on ? how to solve this issue ? and why Postman works !!?

### Edit

Now I verified that the session id cookie in the response of the first request doesn't match the id in the cookie of the second request, So now I know the issue but I don't know how to solve it.

By the Way the problem happens in both chromium 63 and firefox 58.